# can arguments from a class that has objects passed to it work as a valid class to encapsulate the arguments in a method?

Tags: java, arraylist

so i need to make a method to Rent a specific car to a specific customer in a specific
date. and that the car won't be rented at the same time more than once. this is what i cam up with. here are the exact words.

ClassRentalCompany (Main operations)

- Attributes:
  o static list of cars: ArrayList
  (multi-aggregation from Car class)
  o static list of transactions: ArrayList
  (multi-aggregation from RentTransaction class)
- static methods:
  o Buying a new car and adding it to the application: takes
  one argument (Car car): must ensure that the car has not
  been added before.
  o Renting a specific car to a specific customer in a specific
  date: takes three arguments (Car car, Customer
  customer, RentDate date): must ensure that the same car
  won’t be rented twice in the same day

```
   public boolean carRental(RentTransactions newTransaction) {
        boolean carRented = false;
        if (!carList.isEmpty()) {
            for (RentalCars car : carList) {
                //my problem is with the .rentDate.UCI
                if (car.rentDate.equals(newTransaction.rentdate) && car.UCI == newTransaction.UCI) {
                    carRented = true;
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        return carRented;
    }
```

the .rentDate, UCI(unique customer ID) comes from the passed objects in RentTransactions class. the actual classes for date, car and customer are these classes...

```
public class DateOfRenting {
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;

public DateOfRenting(){
      this(0, 0, 0);
  }
public DateOfRenting(int day, int month, int year){
    
      this.day = day;
      this.month=month;
      this.year=year;
  }
public int getday() {
     return day;
    }
public void setday(int day) {
    this.day=day;
    }
public int getmonth() {
     return month;
    }
public void setmonth(int month) {
    this.month=month;
    }
public int getyear() {
     return year;
    }
public void setyear(int year) {
    this.year=year;
    }
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return day+"/"+month+"/"+year;
 }
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()){
            return false;
                }
        DateOfRenting other = (DateOfRenting) obj;
        return this.day == other.day && this.month == other.month && 
                        this.year == other.year;
    }
 
}
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Customers {
  private final int UCI;
  private String Name;
  private int age;
  private String gender;
  
public Customers(){
      this(0, null, 0, null);
  }
public Customers(int UCI, String Name, int age, String gender){
    
      this.UCI = UCI;
      this.Name=Name;
      this.age=age;
      this.gender=gender;
  }
public int getUCI() {
     return UCI;
    }
public String getName() {
     return Name;
    }
public void setName(String Name) {
    this.Name=Name;
    }
public int getage() {
     return age;
    }
public void setage(int age) {
    this.age=age;
    }
public String getgender() {
     return gender;
    }
public void setbrandname(String gender) {
    this.gender=gender;
    }
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "the Unique civil ID is "+UCI+"the customer name is "+Name+
            "the age of the customer is "+age+"the gender of the customer is "+
            gender;
 }
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        if (!super.equals(obj)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        Customers other = (Customers) obj;
        return Objects.equals(UCI, other.UCI);
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RentalCars implements Comparable<RentalCars> {
  private final String UNP;
  private String brandName;
  private double rental_Rates;
  private int wheel_Drive;
  private String color;
  private int milage;
  
  
  
public RentalCars(){
      this(null,null, 0.0, 0, null, 0);
  }
public RentalCars(String UNP, String brandName, double rental_Rates, int wheel_Drive,
   String color, int milage){
    
      this.UNP = UNP;
      this.brandName=brandName;
      this.rental_Rates=rental_Rates;
      this.wheel_Drive=wheel_Drive;
      this.color=color;
      this.milage=milage;
  }
public String getUNP() {
    return UNP;
    }
public String getbrandName() {
     return brandName;
    }
public void setbrandname(String brandName) {
    this.brandName=brandName;
    }
public double getrental_Rates() {
    return rental_Rates;
    }
public void setrental_Rates(double rental_Rates) {
    this.rental_Rates=rental_Rates; 
    } 
public int getwheel_Drive() {
    return wheel_Drive;
    }
public void setwheel_Drive(int wheel_Drive) {
    this.wheel_Drive=wheel_Drive; 
    }
public String getcolor() {
    return color;
    }
public void setcolor(String color) {
    this.color=color; 
    }
public int getmilage() {
    return milage;
    }
public void setmilage(int milage) {
    this.milage=milage; 
    }

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "the Number Plate of the car is "+UNP+"the Car brand is "+brandName+
            "the rent rate of this car is "+rental_Rates+"the wheel drive is "+
            wheel_Drive+"the color of the car is "+color+"the milage is "+milage;
 }
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        if (!super.equals(obj)) {
            return false;
        }
        
        RentalCars other = (RentalCars) obj;
        return Objects.equals(UNP, other.UNP);
    }
public int compareTo(RentalCars rc){
   return UNP.compareTo(rc.UNP);
}
}
```

and the class RentTransactions is this...

```
public class RentTransactions {
    RentalCars car;
    Customers customer;
    DateOfRenting rentDate;
public RentTransactions(){
  }
public RentTransactions(RentalCars car, Customers customer, DateOfRenting rentDate){
    
      this.car = car;
      this.customer=customer;
      this.rentDate=rentDate;
  }
public RentalCars getcar() {
        return car;
    }
public void setcar(RentalCars car) {
        this.car = car;
        }
public Customers getcustomer() {
        return customer;
    }
public void setcustomer(Customers customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
        }
public DateOfRenting getrentDate() {
        return rentDate;
    }
public void setcar(DateOfRenting rentDate) {
        this.rentDate = rentDate;
        }
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return car+"/"+customer+"/"+rentDate;
 }
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()){
            return false;
                }
        RentTransactions other = (RentTransactions) obj;
        return this.car == other.car && this.rentDate == other.rentDate;
    }
}
```

while the main operations method is this...

```
import java.util.*;
public class RentalCompany {
    public static final List<RentalCars> carList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final List<RentTransactions> transactionList = new ArrayList<>();

    public RentalCompany() {
    }

    public static List<RentalCars> getCar() {
        return carList;
    }

    public static List<RentTransactions> getTransaction() {
        return transactionList;
    }
    public static void buyCar(RentalCars car) {
         carList.add(car);
            }
    public static void buycarcheck(String UNP) {
        carList.stream().filter(car -> (car.getUNP().equals(UNP))).forEachOrdered(car -> {
            carList.remove(car);
        });
        
    }
    
    public boolean carRental(RentTransactions newTransaction) {
        boolean carRented = false;
        if (!carList.isEmpty()) {
            for (RentalCars car : carList) {
                //my problem is with the .rentDate.UCI
                if (car.rentDate.equals(newTransaction.rentdate) && car.UCI == newTransaction.UCI) {
                    carRented = true;
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        return carRented;
    }
}
```

you say what i tried and what i expected is for the attributes to be passed

Comment: "*you say what i tried and what i expected is for the attributes to be passed*" - Uh... what?

Comment: Also you should review your formatting (and, in the future, don't forget the *minimal* part of "minimal reproducible example)

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel - Java has perfectly good classes for handling Dates, just use those

Comment: you saw* and what i expected was for the class to pass the attributes

Comment: i was forced to make the Dates rather than use what were available

Comment: `carList` and `transactionList` don't need to  be static - it's almost always bad to have mutable static data.

Comment: What do you intend `buycarcheck` to do?

Comment: `//my problem is with the .rentDate.UCI` - what did you mean here? Why would a rent date have a UCI?

Comment: tom ake sure the same car isn't added twice

Comment: But that's not what that code does - that code (in a very convoluted way) removes all cards with that UCI from the carList. I guess you could call that and then add safely to avoid duplicates, but it's a very strange way to do it.

Comment: the UCI is the Unique customer ID i need to make sure that the car is being rented by once at a time by one customer as 2 customers can't rent the care at the same time

Comment: So staring at your code, I'm still unclear on what you're trying to do and how. I think you're making it harder than it needs to be, though. You can fulfill the requirements by just having a HashSet that stores the combinations of car and rentalDate you've seen so far, and rejects anything that's already in the set.

Comment: If you did have a `.rentalDate` attribute on a car, I would be suspicious - what happens if a car is rented three times? How would the third tell rental tell if matched either of the first two, if the car only stores one date?